# How to display progress bar width as decimal?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

Hi I have this working java script progress bar which shows progress bar as int.
I want to display the result of percentage as decimal?I have searched a lot in google and stack overflow didn't get what I want.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 
<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 10) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width *1  + '%'; //want this result as decimal
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, buddy. Change the JS as follows (and read the comments):

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1); //change the setInterval from 10ms to 1ms, or whatever value you want to make it faster/slower
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 10) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 0.1; //change the increment value to 0.1 instead of 1
      width = Math.round(width * 10) / 10; // round to nearest decimal
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width  + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Though it's not getting the exact decimal.. if the actual result is 1.75% its showing 1.80%  ..kind of worked...I think I will manage thank you for your effort..

Comment: if you want to display it to the nearest TWO decimals, change `width = Math.round(width * 10) / 10;` to `width = Math.round(width * 100) / 100;` and `width += 0.1;` to `width += 0.01;`, but then it will be super slow so adjust the number of ms in the `setInterval()` accordingly